# MySQL. Фигурные скобки. Недокументированная особенность?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb

Добрый день!

Хотелось бы узнать, почему в MySQL и MariaDB (а может и в других БД) проходит такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {some_text(some_number)};
```

some_text - любой текст,
some_number - любое целое число (даже отрицательное).

При этом СУБД не ругается на синтаксис, если значение соответствует [регулярному выражению](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%7B%5Ba-z%5D%2B%28%5B%5Cd%5D%2B%29%3F%5C%28%28%5C-%29%3F%5B%5Cd%5D%2B%5C%29%7D%24%2Fi). И даже возвратит результат аналогично запросу

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = some_number;
```

Это какой-то специальный синтаксис или что? Спасибо.

Comment: Запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = some_number;` вернет ошибку, если в таблице нету столбца с заголовком `some_number`

Comment: Вернет пустую строку, а не ошибку.

Comment: (1054) : unknown column `some number` in `where clause`;

Comment: @IgorKarpenko Под `some_number` ТС имел ввиду любое число а не эту фразу

Comment: Я ведь написал: some_number - любое целое число (даже отрицательное)

Comment: Ну, тут я ничего странного не вижу, по искомому идентификатору не найдено ни одной записи) Вас интересует почему MySql не проверяет тип входящих аргументов, на соответствие заданным при создании таблице ограничениям, когда дело доходит до операций чтения?

Comment: @IgorKarpenko нет. Меня интересует, почему MySQL, MariaDB (а может кто-то ещё) принимает в значение такую строку (и именно такую, которая соответствует описанной регулярке) и  возвращает результат аналогично запросу: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = some_number;`

Comment: @IgorKarpenko Я попробовал запрос `select * from table where id={aaa(10)}` И мне Mysql вернул строку с ID=10, при том что в mysql нет функций с именем `aaa` и у меня в таблице нет даже колонок с таким именем. И вместо `aaa` действительно можно написать любой текст без пробелов и он никак не повлияет на результат запроса. Так что да, загадка ...

Comment: Всё дело в фигурных скобках. Уберите их и получите ошибку

Comment: @SergeyЭто понятно. Вопрос как раз в том, почему фигурные скобки так работают.

Comment: @Sergey неужто? `select * from transactions where id = {some_number};` ругается на синтаксис

Comment: @uorypm Кстати `select * from table where text_column={some_text('TEXT')}` находит и текстовые данные. Так что в круглых скобках может быть как минимум любое значение. А еще `select * from table where column={some_text(column)}` дает все записи таблицы. Так что внутри круглых скобок может быть любое валидное выражение означающее значение.

Comment: @uorypm И `select {some_text(column)} from table` работает и в результатах колонка называется именно column, без включения этого some_text. Так что пока для меня это выглядит как некий поясняющий комментарий. В документации на mysql правда пока ни слова про это не вижу ...

Comment: @Mike Коллега еще такой вариант подсказал: `SELECT {some_text("i" "d")};`

Comment: @uorypm А это еще один интересный синтаксис ибо `select "i" "d"` дает "id", т.е. таким образом mysql строки может объединять через пробел

Comment: @Mike тут дело не только в этом. Неясно почему название поля в результирующей выборке `i`, а не `id`.

Comment: @uorypm при `"i" "d"` так же. тут фигурные скобки не причем. Это отдельная особенность mysql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В [документации на MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html) читаем:

> {identifier expr} is ODBC escape syntax and is accepted for ODBC compatibility. The value is expr. The curly braces in the syntax should be written literally; they are not metasyntax as used elsewhere in syntax descriptions.

В ODBC в фигурных скобках задаются некоторые [особые последовательности](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711838(v=vs.85).aspx), такие как указание интерпретации текста как даты `{d '2016-04-28'}` (так же времени 't' и временной метки 'ts'). Вызова функции `{fn curdate()}` (так же 'call'), задания GUID `{guid '00123...'}`.

Некоторые СУБД поддерживают этот функционал в полной мере, например MS SQL. В них работают только конкретные последовательности. В MySQL для синтаксической совместимости запросов с ODBC внутри фигурных скобок принимается произвольный текст в качестве идентификатора, значение после него интерпретируется как будто оно написано само по себе.

Comment: `SELECT {answer 'Спасибо! :)'} 'Mike';`

Comment: @uorypm Кстати, обнаружил еще такой синтаксис ODBC, рабочий в MySQL: `select *
 from {OJ table1 join table2 on A=B}` вместо OJ Mysql так же готов схавать любой текст :)